# How To Refresh Microsoft Graph Access Token

Tags: firebase, authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using firebase and I'm trying to create a backend function that can fetch an access token using a refresh token.

I've been following along with the [Microsoft Graph Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#refresh-the-access-token) for refreshing an access token but I can not get it to work.

[image]

I don't understand what I could be doing wrong or even how to go about debugging this. Could it have anything to do with the redirect uri that is set in azure console?

Answer (score 0):

As,i can see you are got "invalid_grant" error , please try a new request to the /authorize endpoint and verify that the code_verifier parameter was correct.
Please [image]

Reference doc- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#error-codes-for-token-endpoint-errors

Comment: Could you please also try this in graph explorer - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer